# Naming conventions for Akka messages and actors

Tags: java, akka

I'm currently in the process of making a pretty large Akka based Java application and I'm running into a couple issues that bug me to no end.

My current package layout looks kinda like this:

[image: Project Structure]

My `Mobile` class serving as the supervisor of the actors inside the `actors` package.

Since I don't want to create a new set of Actors for every `HttpClient` and `Account`, I pass those around in message objects, which are stored in the messages package, together with the endpoint `ActorRef` that receives the final result. This does however create a very cluttered `messages` package with a different message for each actor. Eg. `MobileForActor1`, `Actor1ForMobile`, `MobileForActor2` etc. Now my question is, is there a Convention to use for this sort of stuff that deals with this problem and is my structure (`Mobile`->`Actor1`->`Mobile`->`Actor2`->etc.) the way Akka wants it to be or do I have to just sort of waterfall the messages (`Mobile`->`Actor1`->`Actor2`->etc.)?

Right now I'm sending a `ConnectMessage` to my `Mobile` actor which then sends it to `Actor1`, `Actor1` processes it and sends a new message back to `Mobile`, `Mobile` sends that response then to `Actor2` and the cycle continues with a new message being created based on the old message. Eg. `new Message2(message1.foo, message1.bar, message1.baz, newComputatedResult, newComputatedResult2, etc);`

Is this good practice or should I include the old instance (which may contain info that isn't useful anymore) and include the new stuff? Eg. `new Message2(message1, newComputatedResult, newComputatedResult2, etc);`

Or should I do something completely different?

I thought about using TypedActors but those require the use of a waterfall pattern and I don't know how I would pass on the ActorRef of the listener that wants to receive the final result.

I hope I made myself understandable enough because English is not my maiden languages and that the question is clear to everyone.

I'm a beginning Akka developer and love the idea but since the documentation doesn't cover this very well, I figured this would be the best place to ask. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will venture a few comments in response to this because I've dealt with the same issues in my learning curve of Akka. I think you're asking for some rules of thumb so mine are contained herein.

First, creating actors is incredibly cheap; they are very lightweight. So, why not create one for each HttpClient and Account and give them suitable names derived from their identity? This also avoids you having to pass them around as much, probably, decluttering your code.

Second, keep your message names short, focused and starting with a verb. Each message should tell the actor to do something so you want the name to reflect that by using a verb.

Third, sets of messages go with the actor. I usually declare them in the actor class's companion object so that using them is like `ActorClass.MessageName` unless it is within `ActorClass` and then it is just `MessageName`.

Fourth, append a counter to the name of an actor. I often just combine a counter (use `AtomicInteger`) with the name of the type (`Car-1`, `Car-2`, etc.).

If the hierarchy is important to you, I would recommend only appending the parent actor to the name. Something like `Phone-1-in-Car-7` meaning `Phone-1` is contained within `Car-7`.  You can then assemble the hierarchy both programmatically and manually by following the parent links.

I think "Message" in `ConnectMessage` is redundant. Just make the message name be "Connect" or even better "ConnectToThing" (whatever Thing is, if that's relevant).

I wouldn't compound your message names too much like you're suggesting with `Message2`. Use the minimal amount of information to be useful to whomever is going to read those names. I think the lack of response to this may have resulted from this part of your question. I found it confusing as a lot of detail is missing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you show some examples of good message naming? For example I have a Supplier and Consumer. Consumer wants to ask Supplier how many goods it has. How would you name messages for request and for response?

Comment: @TemaBolshakov - How about "GetGoodsCountRequest" and "GetGoodsCountResponse" ?

Comment: not sure these names idiomatic enough in scala. I like the first one but the later looks a bit redundant. May be it's better to respond with Int? Or define type alias for Int, for example `type GoodsCount = Int`. Whats the best option in scala?

Comment: For message types, I use the postfix 'Request' for requests, 'Result' for replies, and 'Op' for executions that do not trigger a reply. For example: `createRequest`, `createReply`, `endConnectionOp`.